# PHP Cassandra module not working

Tags: php, cassandra

I carefully read all Q&A here for about 2 days but could not resolve my issue,  so please do not say that i should read something in first 20 strings of search.

My problem is:

I use Xubuntu, apache2 and php5. Cassandra itself installed and working, cassandra service is running, cassandra cpp installed. 
Command

```
pecl install cassandra
```

works ok, physically `cassandra.so` exist. When i add `extension=cassandra.so` in `php.ini` Apache crashes on start. 
When i try run

```
php -r " Cassandra::cluster()->build();"<br>
```

it returns:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Cassandra' not found in Command line code on line 1
```

I try add extension that not exist in 'php.ini'(like `extension = sdbcibsdbc.so`) but it simply ignored, so problem is not in mistakes or something - `cassandra.so` makes crash. Also previous version(cassandra-1.0.0) simply ignored, not crash Apache but not work too.

What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve issue, but details still unclear. 
This situation, when you can install cassandra php driver but cant add into 'php.ini' means that some of C++ driver dependences not resolved, in my case it was libuv. Have no idea how it possible: libuv-dev without libuv and why pecl throw no errrors.
I remove libuv 1.8.0 and install 1.7.5 - and all OK! Then i try 1.8.0 again and it works too.
 So, probably i miss some step in installation process but it goes without errors or warnings.
As always, most problems will disappear with carefully reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Cassandra you must add extension=cassandra.so to php.ini to enable it:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/cassandra.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/cassandra-1.3.2
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=cassandra.so" to php.ini
```